# Destructor gets called before member function when assigning unique_ptr to a reference

Tags: c++, reference, destructor, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I'm using unique_ptr, and I'm getting some odd results. This is the code:

```
class Sniffer
{
public:
    Sniffer()
    {
        cout << "Sniffer()" << endl;
        s = "String!";
    }

    void operator()()
    {
        cout << "operator()(): " << s << endl;
    }

    ~Sniffer()
    {
        cout << "~Sniffer()" << endl;
    }

private:
    string s;
};


int main()
{
    cout << "Begin scope!" << endl;

    {
        Sniffer& h = *std::unique_ptr<Sniffer>(new Sniffer());   // 1

        //std::unique_ptr<Sniffer> p(new Sniffer());             // 2
        //Sniffer& h = *p;                                       // 2

        h();
    }

    cout << "End scope!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why with code "1", the destructor gets called before operator()(), and "End Scope!", is not printed at all. Code doesn't crash, it executes till the last line, the output I get is:

```
Begin scope!
Sniffer()
~Sniffer()
operator()(): Press any key to continue . . .
```

On the other side code "2" behaves as expected:

```
Begin scope!
Sniffer()
operator()(): String!
~Sniffer()
End scope!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The reason I'm using a reference is only because I felt `h()` felt more natural than `(*p)()` or `p->operator()()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this statement

```
Sniffer& h = *std::unique_ptr<Sniffer>(new Sniffer());
```

a temporary object of type `std::unique_ptr<Sniffer>` is created that is destroyed at the end of execution of the statement.

Thus reference `h` is invalid in the scope of the code block.

In this statement

```
std::unique_ptr<Sniffer> p(new Sniffer());             // 2
```

object p is created and will be alive until the end of the code block. So reference `h`

```
Sniffer& h = *p;
```

will be valid in this scope.

Answer (score 2):

The `std::unique_pointer<Sniffer>` is a temporary in your "1", so is destroyed after the statement completes.      Its destructor destroys the `Sniffer` object, before the next statement (`h();`) is reached.   `h` is a dangling reference, so the result of `h()` (i.e. `h.operator()()`) is undefined.

In your case "2", the object `p` continues to exist until the end of the containing scope, which is after the statement `h();`

Answer (score 1):

It because when you do

```
Sniffer& h = *std::unique_ptr<Sniffer>(new Sniffer());
```

the `std::unique_ptr` object you create is *temporary* and is destructed, leaving you with a reference to an object that no longer exists and you enter the land of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

When you do

```
std::unique_ptr<Sniffer> p(new Sniffer());
```

you create an actual non-temporary object `p` which you of course could have references to during its life-time.

Comment: you should precise (it's obvious i know but still) that the dynamic object  Sniffer to which h actually points is deleted by destructor of the temporary unique_ptr

Answer (score 1):

Line `1` creates a temporary unique_ptr object which is dereferenced and the result of that is what the reference `h` will then point to. However, as the unique_ptr object is a temporary, its destructor will be called at the semicolon (See [object lifetime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime)). This will also call the destructor of the `Sniffer` object that the temporary unique_ptr pointed to.

The code `2` is really how you should be using unique_ptr. Or even better use C++14's [`make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).

The whole purpose of unique_ptr is that whatever it points to will automatically be destroyed (or deleted by a custom deleter) when the unique_ptr object goes out of scope. In line `1` it goes out of scope even before you used its contents. See [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

> std::unique_ptr is a smart pointer that retains sole ownership of an object through a pointer and destroys that object when the unique_ptr goes out of scope.